# Generate n random numbers in interval from 0 to k, where n can be greater than k

Tags: c, sorting, random

I know that there are many questions about random numbers, but I am trying to make a code that generate `n` numbers in the interval [0, k]. This numbers can repeat, but I don't want a lot of repetition of the same number, example:

For 5 numbers in [0, 10], I don't want: `1 1 3 3 3`.

For 10 numbers in [0, 10], I don't want: `1 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 8 8`.

For 5 numbers in [0, 10], I want something like : `0 2 3 3 4`.

For 5 numbers in [0, 10], I want something like : `0 0 1 2 4 5 5 5 7 10`.

Ok, this is not hard to do, I did it like this:

```
static void random_numbers(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int i, interval;

    interval = 1000000;
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%u\n", (unsigned int) rand() % (interval + 1));
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want to generate this numbers in ascending and descending order too. I was trying to make it with something like:

```
static void ascending(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int i, acc;

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    for(i = 0, acc = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        acc += (unsigned int) rand() % 10; /* For descending, just change + to - */
        printf("%u\n", acc);
    }
}
```

This code will generate random numbers, and sometimes will repeat numbers, that's what I want. But can generate, if `n` is 100 for example, the maximum number 900. I have not figured out a way to put an interval on it.

I thought a way but is not good, using the `random_numbers` function to generate the numbers, store them in array and sort them (ascending or descending) and after print it, but it will take time and memory.

The purpose of this code is generate data for testing sort algorithms. I don't want to download DataSets, I want to make my own function. The numbers will be printed on `stdout`, and using the redirection on linux, I will store them in a file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the requirement “ This numbers can repeat, but without the possibility of all numbers or most of them be equal.” precisely?

Comment: Sorry, my former comment was crap/lazy. I realized soon that the difficulty is the combo of generating ascending/descending random numbers in an interval, not merely any order of numbers within an interval. There, since your goal is to test sorting algorithms, you could use one of them when generating these data sets to sort the data in ascending/descending order post -- or just use `qsort`.

Comment: @FUZxxl , edited. I don't want poorly distributed numbers.

Comment: @X0R40 Your requirement is still extremely unclear. `0 2 3 3 4` is a completely valid random  set made according to your specification. If you generate random sets, of course some of them will have many duplicates. Please specify *exactly* (and not just by giving some examples) when a set has “most numbers equal.”

Comment: @FUZxxl, I do not want most of the numbers equals. Just it. I want set of numbers, randomly generated but with some repetitions. The examples is just to show that I don't want many repetitios on my set of numbers.

Comment: @X0R40 Define “most.” Please, your description is incredibly imprecise. In order to make something that satisfies your description, I need a description that is sufficiently precise.

Comment: @FUZxxl, The example ` 1 1 3 3 3` has only two numbers. Other example is `2 2 2 2 2`, and has only one number repeated. I want the numbers more distributed, and some numbers repeated (not most of them (not the `majority`)). I don't want the `majority` of the numbers generated are repeated with little distribution on the interval [0, k].

Comment: @X0R40 “more distributed,” “some numbers,” “little distribution,” all the terms are imprecise. Please define them *precisely.* Give me a procedure with which I can exactly decide if a set is acceptable or not. If the definition is  “at least half of the set members appear only once,” then `0 2 3 3 4` would be an acceptable set as 3 out of the 5 numbers (more than half) appear only once, but you said it isn't acceptable. Please be precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this.  
static void ascending(unsigned int n, int gap) {
    int i, ofs, rnum;
    ofs = 0; // ofs at 0  
    srandom((int) time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, ofs += gap) { // up the ofs by gap.  
        rnum = ofs + rand() % gap;
        printf("%d\n", rnum);
    }
}  

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n, gap;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    gap = atoi(argv[2]);
    ascending(20, 11);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this has no guarantee about the interval [0, k]. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: We just need to determine the gap appropriately. k/n will be the gap.

Comment: And when n is greater than k ? Like k = 1000000 and n = 10000000 ?

Comment: Probably when the requirements change (or better understood by coder), code may have to change ;)

Comment: Yes, what I am in doubt is when n can be greater than k. I wrote this on title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it directly in one operation, decompose into two:

1. Generate n random numbers in the interval [0..k]
2. Sorting.

So, something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int compare_asc(const void * uint1, const void * uint2)
{
    return (*(const unsigned int *) uint1) - 
          (*(const unsigned int *) uint2);
}

static int compare_desc(const void * uint1, const void * uint2) 
{
    return compare_asc(uint2, uint1);
}

unsigned int * random_range(unsigned int n, unsigned int k)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int * range= malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * n);
    if (range) {
       for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          range[i] = rand() % k;
       }
    }
    return range;
}

unsigned int * random_ascending(unsigned int n, unsigned int k)
{
    unsigned int * range = random_range(n, k);
    if(range) {
        qsort(range, n, sizeof(unsigned int), compare_asc);
    }
    return range;
}

// implementing random_descending(n,k) is left as exercise ...

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    unsigned int k = 22, n = 42, i;
    unsigned int * range;
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    range = random_ascending(n, k);
    if(range) {
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("range[%d] = %d\n", i, range[i]);
        }
        free(range); // need to free
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Unable to allocate necessary memory...\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote in the end of question that it was a way that I thought to solve. But like I said, it will take time and memory. I want to generate more than 5 million numbers.

Comment: @X0R40 then consider writing the 5 million numbers to a file first, memory mapping that file into memory and the using pointer arithmetic to sort your file as an array... That way the burden of memory management is shifted onto the OS instead of your program code. Note that with 5 million numbers you *will* be able to notice (statistically) from the distribution whether or not you played silly buggers with 'range' to 'speed up' the problem. In particular if you get answers like [0, 5M, ...] then you will have 5M - 1 copies of the value 5M and a 0 in your file.

Comment: @X0R40 also, note that 5 million numbers of type `unsigned int` is on 32 bit machines and many 64 bit machines just 5 * 4 MB = 20MB. All things considered, that's not all that much memory to allocate these days...